# How to use mitmdump inside AWS CodeBuild?

Tags: http, https, aws-codebuild, mitmproxy

I need to log all HTTPS traffic from an AWS CodeBuild into a file. I'm trying to do this by using [mitmdump (mitmproxy cli)](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/)

This is my current buildspec.yml

```yaml
version: 0.2

phases:
  build:
    on-failure: CONTINUE
    commands:
      - sudo apt-get update
      - sudo apt-get -y install mitmproxy
      - mitmdump -w mitmdump.txt > mitmlog.txt &
      - sleep 5 # just to be sure
      - curl https://github.com/
      # there will be a lot of other https requests from this point which I can't control
      # they will simply be placed here and executed
artifacts:
  files:
    - 'mitmdump.txt'
    - 'mitmlog.txt'
```

The results are, `mitmdump.txt` empty and `mitmlog.txt` has only one line written:

> Proxy server listening at http://*:8080

I've also tried:

```
- mitmdump --listen-port 443 -w mitmdump.txt > mitmlog.txt &
```

and

```
- mitmdump --listen-port 80 -w mitmdump.txt > mitmlog.txt &
```

But still same results.

What is the correct way of using `mitmdump` in this scenario?

Comment: You forgot to add the CA certificate created/used by mitmproxy to the list of trusted certificates e.g. on Linux level or wherever the internet using applications expect it (not sure about curl). Without that all applications will block network usage because of untrusted root CA used.

Comment: More fundamentally, it looks like you're not redirecting any traffic to mitmproxy, so nothing is picked up. Compare this to `curl -x http://localhost:8080/ http://example.com`.

Comment: @MaximilianHils, I see, is there any way to redirect all requests to the proxy without having to change the curl command?

Comment: That depends on the used OS. See e.g. this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/999274/how-to-make-curl-use-proxy-automatically

Comment: Hey @Robert, it worked! Now I just have to figure out how to generate the CA cert with mitmdump. Is it possible?

Comment: @PedroHenrique Mitmproxy/mitmdump/mitmweb automatically generate an CA root certificate on first start. Check `~/.mitmproxy` https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-certificates/#the-mitmproxy-certificate-authority

Comment: Hey guys I made it work, I didn't even need the CA certs in my scenario, simply using `--ssl-insecure` did the trick. Another thing I was doing wrong was pointing to the wrong proxy server URL (`-x https://` when it should be `-x http://`). Now I'm facing another problem, some requests are not going through the proxy (some nodejs scripts using `node-fetch` for example). Even though I've set all env variables pointing to `mitmdump` address. `HTTP_PROXY`, `HTTPS_PROXY`, `GLOBAL_AGENT_HTTP_PROXY`, `GLOBAL_AGENT_HTTPS_PROXY` and `GLOBAL_AGENT_NO_PROXY`, are all pointing to `http://localhost:8080`.

Comment: Little update, I was able to force redirect all traffic to the proxy by following this guide: https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/howto-transparent/. Now those requests coming from nodejs are being captured, except, the ones that were working before are not anymore (git clone for example).

Comment: Hey @Robert, is it possible to change the location of the certs generated by mitmdump? I'm following the transparent proxy guide and, apparently, inside of an AWS CodeBuild, the user `mitmproxyuser` does not have access to write to `~/.mitmproxy`. I'm using this recommended command line to start the process: `sudo -u mitmproxyuser -H bash -c 'mitmdump ...'`

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to specify the home directory. I only know the way described i the start-process for mitmproxy with docker which allows you to specify the path that is in the end mapped in the docker image to `~/.mitmproxy`. https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/8023b224985d5853a624ebd4a1ff7b8d79ece433/release/docker/DockerHub-README.md